# C++ nested loop prime number

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, primes

I have a question that I couldn’t solve , I worked hard and didn’t have a total solution
I need to type a number of soldiers and check out if the
serial numbers product = the number of soldiers
**and**
check if one of the serial numbers is **PRIME**.
As a result I need to print the 2 serial numbers that bring me the product once
For example:

Number = 20

I need to print

2 10

4 5

Number = 120

I need to print

2 60

3 40

5 24

6*20 Cant be printed because none of them is prime number
and so on

Number = 48

I need to print

2 24

3 16

4*12 Cant be printed because none of them is prime number

And so on
I did everything alright except finding if one of the numbers is prime
the code is :

```
int armysize;

cout << "Please type how many soldiers do you have in your army:" << endl;

cin >> armysize;

int serialnumproduct = 0; 

for (int soldiernum = 2; soldiernum < sqrt(armysize); soldiernum++)
{
    
    for (int nextsoldier = 2; nextsoldier <= armysize/2; nextsoldier++)
    {
        serialnumproduct = soldiernum * nextsoldier; 

        if (serialnumproduct == armysize && soldiernum != nextsoldier)
            cout << soldiernum << " * " << nextsoldier << " = " <<
                   serialnumproduct << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I don't see any code having to do with primes. Is your question, "how do I check if a number is prime?"

Comment: The question is , how can I check if 1 or the numbers that make the product that I found is prime
for example
the number 400
can bring me:
2 * 200 
4 * 100
5*80
8*50
10*40
16*25

and the only results that i want are:
2*200 and 5*80

Answer (score 0):

A function such as this one should tell you wether a number is prime or not. You need to make sure you are dealing with numbers that can fit in an `int` on your machine, or update the code

```
bool IsPrime (int ninteger) 
{
bool prime (true);
for(auto i = 2 ; i<ninteger ; ++i)
{
if (ninteger%i == 0)
prime = false;
}
return prime;
}
```

Comment: This is the least efficient solution possible that isn't also a joke, doing over two billion iterations every single time.

Comment: it doesnt help me because I can't add extra programs :( , still beginner

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is a function to show if `soldiernum` is a prime number or not. I used a `prime_test()` function and used it on line 34 as an `if()` statement, so the code see if it should  use the `soldiernum` or not.

This was the result:

```
Please type how many soldiers do you have in your army:
400
2 * 200 = 400
5 * 80 = 400
```

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;
    bool prime_test (int num) 
    {
    bool prime (true);
    for(int i = 2 ; i<num; ++i)
    {
    if (num%i == 0)
    prime = false;
    }
    return prime;
    }
    int main(){ 
    int armysize;
    int count=2;
    bool isPrime = true;

    cout << "Please type how many soldiers do you have in your army:" << endl;

    cin >> armysize;

    int serialnumproduct = 0; 


    for (int soldiernum = 2; soldiernum < sqrt(armysize); soldiernum++){

        for (int nextsoldier = 2; nextsoldier <= armysize/2; nextsoldier++)
        {
            serialnumproduct = soldiernum * nextsoldier; 

            if (serialnumproduct == armysize && soldiernum != nextsoldier)
                if(prime_test(soldiernum)==true) {
        
                cout << soldiernum << " * " << nextsoldier << " = " <<
                       serialnumproduct << endl;
                }   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```